# How to force field type to range in Grocery Crud?

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I need a range input to get an integer between 100 and 500 in Grocery Crud. Currently it's a normal text input field, and field_type() method doesn't have the range option. Is there a solution to add Bootstrap range instead?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple way, you can use type number at input form

```
<input type="number" name="grocery" id="grocery" min="100" max="500" />
```

Another way you can use javascript

```
<script>
  function integerInRange(value, min, max) {

      if(value < min || value > max)
        {
            document.getElementById("grocery").value = "500";
            alert("min = 100 and max = 500");
        }
      }
</script>
```

and in your view

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="grocery" id="grocery" onkeyup="integerInRange(this.value, 100, 500)" />
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. My problem is not to force the user to give the right input. I would like to add a range for practical and design reasons.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/ (range inputs)

Comment: Ok I see, maybe you can try this one <?php
$range = 100;
        for ($num=1; $num<$range; $num++){ echo '
                <option value="' .+$num. '">' .$num. '</option>'; }?> </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="grocery" id="grocery"?>" required/>           
            </div>
 ?>  hope this one can help you,

Comment: Hello, thank you for your efforts :) The solution for this was kinda complicated. (especially it's only an input type change). I've created a template file for it, a function to fetch the template, and used GC's callback_add/edit/read fields.